# Updating SharePoint Online List Hyperlinks - Multiple lines of text

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell

We recently migrated domains and have a Sharepoint list with hundreds of hyperlinks.

There are a handful of scripts out there for updating list items with URL fields, but am having issues translating how to do this for the "Multiple lines of text" data type.

Is there a way to run powershell PnP for Sharepoint to update these links ?

Example would be:

**Current Link**

```
mywebsite.domain1.com
```

**New Link**

```
mywebsite.domain2.com
```

Comment: In your "Multiple lines of text" field, does it have many URL's or only one URL per row ??

Answer (score 0):

We can use PnP PowerShell to achieve it, the following script for your reference.

```
$URL='https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/team'
$ListTitle="CL1120"
$FieldName="MultipleField"
$OldUrl="mywebsite.domain1.com"
$NewUrl="mywebsite.domain2.com"
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $URL –Credentials (Get-Credential)

$Items=Get-PnPListItem -List $ListTitle -Fields "ID",$FieldName
foreach($Item in $Items){  
    $MultiFieldVal= $Item[$FieldName]    
    $NewVal=$MultiFieldVal -replace $OldUrl,$NewUrl 
    Set-PnPListItem -List $ListTitle -Identity $Item.Id -Values @{$FieldName = $NewVal}
}
```